# Find natural number $n$ such that $23^n+1971$ is a square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have faced a problem as follows:

Find all natural number $n$ such that $23^n+1971$ is a square number.

I can show that $n$ must congruence to 2 mod 4 but from that I can deduce nothing.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's enough: you have proven that $n$ is even. Therefore $23^n$ is itself a square, and it can't be too close to another square. That rules out any possible solutions with $n>2$. As for $n=2$, it has to be checked directly: $1971+529=?$

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=4k+2$, then $23^n+1971=m^2\implies 1971=(m+23^{2k+1})(m-23^{2k+1})$.
We know $1971=73\cdot3^3$ so there is only a small finite number of tests needed.